# A* (A star) Path finding slows everything when there is no path

Tags: path-finding, a-star, breadth-first-search, real-time-strategy

In my RTS game I used BFS, it is very slow.

So i am using A* now, it is very fast to find a path, but if there is no possible path it makes everything about to be hanged.

To solve this i tried to get out of the loop if it takes much considering to the linear distance between src & dst. But in some cases where the linear distance is very short but path is long it fails.

Comment: How about distributing the calculation over multiple frames, and perhaps using the most promising direction before full answer is available, if waiting for it is unacceptable?

Comment: OK I am checking how it results

Comment: See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32813/32831#32831

Comment: i tried distributing the pathfinding by threading, but the problem still remains, that particular unit stands for long time....the unit stops only when destination is blocked.....so i think HPA* would also have the same problem......
cant it be somehow calculated if there is a path or not easily